# .net and google authentication

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have worked with the google example of working with the google calendar.  My app worked great until they recently changed the API.  I am finding their documentation to be a little overwhelming and not very useful.  I have used this [example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp/Program.vb?repo=samples).

I am getting the following error

> An unhandled exception of type: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Google.Apis.Auth.dll

Additional information: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set

I have no clue what the client secret is or what they are talking about.  I have searched for the phrase and nothing is coming back with any information.  What is the client scret and how do I set it?

Here is the line of code Im getting the error.

```
 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
                    New FileDataStore("CalendarSample")).Result
```

I have the json file that they setup for me and it appears to be reading it.  I am sure I should be modifying that file, but I cannot find anything with exact instructions on it.

Any help would be great.  What I will do in the end is just add and delete entries from a google calendar.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried and get solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are working with Oauth2 here.

The basic code to authenticate to Google Calendar using the nugget package  [Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)

```
string clientId = "";//From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
 string clientSecret = "";//From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
 string userName = ""//  A string used to identify a user.
 string[] scopes = new string[] {
    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
    CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
 };

// here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets {
        ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret
    }, scopes, userName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleCalendar.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

Once you are authenticated you can then use create a calendar service to access google calendar

```
// Create the service.
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
    });
```

Code riped from the tutorial [Google Calendar API with C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/) the tutorial is kept up to date.

Comment: I never did get an answer.